# Confused on factor levels and mutating with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replace NA values in categorical columns in my dataset, using ifelse, but when I try it is re-encoding the other values.  I'm sure something is going on with the factor levels, I just am not aware of what I could do to solve this.  Note how the difference in the mpg change after applying my ifelse, which should only impact the records with NAs?

```
mtcars2 = mtcars

mtcars2$mpg = as.factor(mtcars2$mpg)
mtcars2$mpg[1]=NA
mtcars2$mpg[2]=NA

hmm = mtcars2 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(is.factor, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x)==TRUE, "NO VALUE", x)

hmm
###vs
mtcars2
```

Comment: If you want to create new levels, first change the `levels`.  Here, I think it is coercing to `character`  Or wrap with `factor` i.e. `hmm = mtcars2 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(is.factor, funs(factor(ifelse(is.na(.), "NO VALUE", .)))
 )`

Comment: It is not the issue with `dplyr`  You can check `with(mtcars2, ifelse(is.na(mpg), "NO VALUE", mpg))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other folks have already pointed out some issues:

1) `ifelse` repeats atomic values, which results in "de-factoring":

```
x <- factor( 1:3 )
# [1] 1 2 3               # Factor
# Levels: 1 2 3

ifelse( is.na(x), x, x )  # Effectively "do nothing"
# [1] 1 2 3               # No longer a factor
```

2) You defined a factor over numeric values, which coerces them to character. This may be undesirable and lead to unexpected behavior if you later assume that they are still numeric:

```
levels(factor(1:3))       # Factor defined over numeric values
# [1] "1" "2" "3"         #  but has character levels
```

With that said, if your goal is to replace NAs in a factor with another value, then `forcats::fct_explicit_na()` is the function you're looking for:

```
mhm <- mtcars2 %>% mutate_if( is.factor, fct_explicit_na, "NO VALUE" )
#         mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  NO VALUE   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2  NO VALUE   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3      22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# ...

mhm$mpg
# [1] NO VALUE NO VALUE 22.8     21.4     18.7    ...
# 26 Levels: 10.4 13.3 14.3 14.7 15 15.2 ... NO VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

The `yes` and `no` arguments to `ifelse` aren't meant to be vectors, but atomics that get repeated whenever the test is true.  That's why it fails to "rebuild" the factor, whether using `dplyr` or `base`, as in @akrun's comment.

You can achieve what you want using the `coalesce` function from `dplyr`, but you'll have to turn the variable into a `character` first, otherwise it'll fail because you are adding values that aren't a part of the `factor`'s levels:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars2 = mtcars

mtcars2$mpg = as.character(mtcars2$mpg)
mtcars2$mpg[1]=NA
mtcars2$mpg[2]=NA

hmm = mtcars2 %>% mutate_if(is.character, coalesce, "NO VALUE")
```

You can then convert it into a `factor` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

So since you refer that your columns are categorical, I used the `HairEyeColor` dataset, which has columns with categorical and quantitative data.

I am not sure if the column you're working with is factor or character, though. 
You can check that by using `class()`

If it is character, then this should work:

```
data<-as_tibble(HairEyeColor)

data$Eye[2]<-NA
data$Eye[3]<-NA

hmm <- data %>% mutate_if(is.character, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x)==TRUE, "NO VALUE", x))
```

If factor,

```
data<-as_tibble(HairEyeColor)

data$Eye<-as.factor(data$Eye)
class(data$Eye)
data$Eye[2]<-NA
data$Eye[3]<-NA

hmm <- data %>% mutate_if(is.factor, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x)==TRUE, "NO VALUE", x))
```

Hope it helps!